# Team viewer data usage

Tags: file-transfer, teamviewer

I connect my low speed internet in my country to my high speed internet pc in another country (my own pc). Now, consider I download sth from that pc, which data usage it is using in this case? Also, if I want to transfer that file from that pc to my laptop again which internet data is used and how can I know the usage?

Answer (score 1):

If you download it on the remote PC, then you are using that PC's connection. Your local computer is merely 'watching it happen'.

If you then transfer that file to your local computer, you are then using **both** connections, one to send, the other to receive.

The data usage is the same as your normal remote connection, plus approximately the size of the file at each transfer - so the local computer uses 'remote connection, plus file size', the remote computer uses 'remote connection, plus file size **x2**'